# Error in WCF Service in VB.NET using ADO.NET to Connect SQL database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, wcf, ado.net, wcf-data-services

I have WCF service "WcfService" with few functions, they are working good, except my one function which is responsible for getting data from sql server. I'm not good familiar with vb.net, my experience comes from vba. I found some code on the Internet and did some small changes, but function doesn't work. I think the problem is wrong definition in ServiceContract() and DataContract(). WCF Test Client in Visual Studio Express for Web 2015 shows me this error description "This operation is no supported in the WCF Test Client because it uses type WcfService Cookies Data"

IService1.vb.

```
<ServiceContract()>
    Public Interface IService1
      <OperationContract()>
      Function GetCookiesPriceDS(ByVal nameOfCookie As String) As CookiesData
    End Interface

<DataContract()>
Public Class CookiesData
    Public Sub New()
        CustomersTable = New DataTable("TblCookies")
    End Sub

    <DataMember()>
     Public Property CustomersTable() As DataTable
End Class
```

Service1.scv

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1
Public Function GetCookiesPriceDS(ByVal nameOfCookie As String) _
        As CookiesData Implements IService1.GetCookiesPriceDS

        Using con As New SqlConnection("Server= xyz\SQLEXPRESS; Database = Cookies2;" &
            " Integrated Security = true;")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select CookiesPrice from tblCookies where " &
                                        "CookiesName='" & nameOfCookie & "'")
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        Dim ck As New CookiesData()
                        sda.Fill(ck.CustomersTable)
                        Return ck
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: VS Express 2015?  Pretty sure the Express stuff ended with 2012 when it was replaced by the Community Edition.

Comment: Yes VS Express 2015 for Web